# Connect to Athena using JDBC in a maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jdbc, amazon-athena

I'm trying to connect to the Amazon Athena, using jdbc in a maven project, but an exception is being raised. I think that the class is not being found. In Athena's guide it  says:

> 2. Set the JDBC property, aws_credentials_provider_class, equal to the class name, and include itin your classpath. [(1)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/athena-ug.pdf)

Since I'm using eclipse, I thought that the class would be already in the classpath, but apparently not. I tested the code in a simple java project (not maven) and it worked.

**AmazonCredentialsProvider.java**:

```
package athena;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;

public class AmazonCredentials implements AWSCredentials {
    @Override public String getAWSAccessKeyId() { return "..."; }
    @Override public String getAWSSecretKey() { return "..."; }
}
```

**AmazonCredentialsProvider.java**:

```
package athena;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider;

public class AmazonCredentialsProvider implements AWSCredentialsProvider {
    @Override public AWSCredentials getCredentials() { return new AmazonCredentials(); }
    @Override public void refresh() {}
}
```

The code snippet of the connection :

```
Class.forName("com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver");

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("user", user);
properties.setProperty("password", password);

properties.setProperty("aws_credentials_provider_class", "athena.AmazonCredentialsProvider");
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:awsathena://athena." + region + ".amazonaws.com:443", properties);
```

The exception:

> java.sql.SQLException: Failed to load AWS credentials provider class:
>   athena.AmazonCredentialsProvider  at
>   com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriverPropertiesFactory.lambda$parseProperties$2(AthenaDriverPropertiesFactory.java:52)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriverPropertiesFactory.setClientConfigProperty(AthenaDriverPropertiesFactory.java:159)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriverPropertiesFactory.parseProperties(AthenaDriverPropertiesFactory.java:40)
>     at
>   com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver.connect(AthenaDriver.java:110)
>     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)  at
>   athena.Athena.(Athena.java:94)  at
>   services.GraphService.verify(GraphService.java:194)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$VoidOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:183)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.lambda$apply$0(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:405)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$AsyncResponder$2$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:843)
>     at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)  at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$AsyncResponder$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:838)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: athena.AmazonCredentialsProvider    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriverPropertiesFactory.lambda$parseProperties$2(AthenaDriverPropertiesFactory.java:44)
>     ... 31 more

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest version of the JDBC driver?

If yes, try to follow these instructions:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection-with-maven.html