# Class not found in dynamic web project using maven in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-3, m2eclipse

I'm trying to connect to a JDBC database in my maven project, however the provider class path could not be found in the project. When I try the same code in a normal java project it works. Does anyone know how to include the classpath or something to solve this problem?

```
Class.forName("com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriver");

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty("user", user);
properties.setProperty("password", password);
properties.setProperty("aws_credentials_provider_class", "athena.AmazonCredentialsProvider");

connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:awsathena://athena.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:443", properties);
```

**pom.xml**:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>PSRCore.Graph2</groupId>
    <artifactId>PSRCore.Graph2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.3</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>redshift</id>
            <url>http://redshift-maven-repository.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
            <artifactId>redshift-jdbc42</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.1001</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ben-manes.caffeine</groupId>
            <artifactId>caffeine</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>PSRCore.Graph2</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
>   psrcore/graph2/athena/AmazonCredentialsProvider
>
> at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>
> at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>
> at 
>   com.amazonaws.athena.jdbc.AthenaDriverPropertiesFactory.lambda$parseProperties$2 (AthenaDriverPropertiesFactory.java:44)
>
> ... 31 more

Comment: Is AmazonCredentialsProvider your own class? Per your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391630/connect-to-athena-using-jdbc-in-a-maven-project)..

Comment: @Vasan Yes, it's my own class, but regardless of the code within the class, it's never found.